# Improving text file reading speed

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I use a program to read in a text file that is always formatted the same way (see image). My source code works fine, but it seems a **bit long** to me. Does anyone have any suggestion to make it look **shorter** / nicer?

My only concern is to find out the 4 values for xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax from the file, and the points. The point is that I need 6 lines each for the 4 values. The reason I couldn't use a for loop is because I couldn't find a way to specifically reference xmin / xmax / ymin / ymax.

Is there a faster solution than `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` (loading the entire file)?

[image: screenshot of the text file]

`akt_Zeile` means current line in English.
`erfolg` means success, in sense of typecast.
`PunkteListe` means List of/with Points.

```
#Disable Warning IDE1006 ' Benennungsstile 'Naming rule violation
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
Public NotInheritable Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub Button_lesen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_lesen.Click
        Await Task.Run(Sub() einlesen_und_testen())
    End Sub

    Private Sub einlesen_und_testen()
        Dim Pfad As String
        Using OFD1 As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFD1.Title = "Datei auswählen"
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Textdateien", ".txt"))
            OFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            Dim Result As CommonFileDialogResult
            Me.Invoke(Sub() Result = OFD1.ShowDialog())
            If Result = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Pfad = OFD1.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        Me.Invoke(Sub() Button_lesen.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0)) 'yellow

        Dim readText() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Pfad, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        Dim xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, Anzahl_Punkte As Integer

        Dim akt_Zeile1 As String = readText(5).Substring(6, readText(5).Length - 6)
        Dim erfolgreich1 As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(akt_Zeile1, xmin)
        If Not erfolgreich1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Could not parse ‘String’ to ‘Integer’.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Return
        End If
        Dim akt_Zeile2 As String = readText(6).Substring(6, readText(6).Length - 6)
        Dim erfolgreich2 As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(akt_Zeile2, xmax)
        If Not erfolgreich2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Could not parse ‘String’ to ‘Integer’.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Return
        End If
        Dim akt_Zeile3 As String = readText(7).Substring(6, readText(7).Length - 6)
        Dim erfolgreich3 As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(akt_Zeile3, ymin)
        If Not erfolgreich3 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Could not parse ‘String’ to ‘Integer’.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Return
        End If
        Dim akt_Zeile4 As String = readText(8).Substring(6, readText(8).Length - 6)
        Dim erfolgreich4 As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(akt_Zeile4, ymax)
        If Not erfolgreich4 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Could not parse ‘String’ to ‘Integer’.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Return
        End If
        Dim akt_Zeile5 As String = readText(10).Substring(4, 3)
        Dim erfolgreich5 As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(akt_Zeile5, Anzahl_Punkte)
        If Not erfolgreich5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Could not parse ‘String’ to ‘Integer’.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Return
        End If

        Dim PunkteListe As New List(Of PointF)
        For i As Integer = 11 To readText.Length - 2 Step 1 'Length - 2 because the last line is named “End” (without line break) .
            Dim aktuelle_Zeile() As String = readText(i).Split(Convert.ToChar(9))
            Dim _1 As Single
            Dim erfolg1 As Boolean = Single.TryParse(aktuelle_Zeile(0), _1)
            Dim _2 As Single
            Dim erfolg2 As Boolean = Single.TryParse(aktuelle_Zeile(1), _2)
            If erfolg1 AndAlso erfolg2 Then
                PunkteListe.Add(New PointF(_1, _2))
            Else
                MessageBox.Show($"Could not parse ‘String’ to ‘Single’. Line #{i + 1}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                Return
            End If
        Next

        Me.Invoke(Sub() Button_lesen.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 225, 0)) 'green
    End Sub
End Class
#Enable Warning IDE1006 ' Benennungsstile
```

Comment: So you haven't really told us exactly what part of this is slow, assuming that it's the ReadAllLines.  You could just seek and read the 4 lines you're after without loading the entire file

Comment: Hi @Hursey, that's correct, it's ReadAllLines. How can I seek?. And well, I have to use ReadAllLines later on to get the points in my List(of PointF).

Comment: Probably the best place to start, particularly the section on streams https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimisation of working code is not a topic for SO.

Comment: @jmcilhinney "...optimisation of working code is not a topic for SO". Really? Why not?

Comment: How fast does it need to be? It's only a few kB by the look of it. I'd be inclined to read it all and keep it in memory for any other parts of it might need later, to save re-reading it.

Comment: Possibly another option - since you say the file is always formatted the same way - might be to create a class against an XML or JSON file and deserialize directly (using JSON.NET for example). Nice and clean.

Comment: @SteveCinq, *"Is there a faster solution than System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (loading the entire file)?"* is hardly a question about a specific issue. If the OP wants to read the entire file then they can research how to read an entire file and time the performance. This question is fishing.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach is to use [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.5#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) with `LINQ` to skip the first lines, since the question mentioned the structure is always the same then assume skipping always the same lines, and taking only the lines that are of interest.

Unlike `File.ReadAllLines`, `File.ReadLines` advantage is that it won't load the entire file.

A simple example based on the file structure similar to the question:

```
Imports System.IO

Sub Main()
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("C:\temp\test.txt").Skip(5).Take(4).ToArray()
        Console.WriteLine(line)
    Next
End Sub
```